# Why are WPF types inside the System.Windows namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it because this technology is tied to Windows? Reason I ask is I read and have been told here that it's not dependent on Windows, so can be ported to other platforms.

In that case shouldn't it be in a non-Windows namespace?

My colleague told me it's because Microsoft didn't want WPF to be ported to other platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace doesn't really matter.  Mono has a pretty good implementation of System.Windows.Forms that runs on Windows, Linux, and OS X.

Comment: Thanks, do you know which namespace they use for it on Mono, the same one?

Comment: The namespace *has* to be System.Windows.Forms for binary and source compatibility with existing software written for Windows.  However, the actual implementation is referred to by the Mono project as Managed.Windows.Forms, since this was a later implementation of the System.Windows.Forms namespace entirely in managed code.  Earlier implementations tried to use libwine or do other nasty hacks, so the Managed.Windows.Forms name serves only to identify the specific implementation of the namespace.  You would never use the namespace Managed.Windows.Forms in actual code.

Answer (score 2):

WPF means  **Windows** Presentation Foundation.

And it does not directly indicate whether it is possible (or allowed) to port it to other platforms. WinForms is present in Mono, WPF not (yet).

Answer (score 1):

I heard the "Windows" is not supposed to mean "Microsoft Windows (TM)" in this context, but simply a plural form of the word "window".